# Next.js computes strange first load size

Tags: next.js

My Next.js project yields the following output on build:

```
Page                            Size     First Load
┌ ● /                           351 B        135 kB
├   /_app                       869 B       63.2 kB
├ ● /p/markdown                 3.3 kB       143 kB
├ ● /p/page2                    3.24 kB      143 kB
└ ● /p/test                     2.22 kB      142 kB
+ shared by all                 63.2 kB
  ├ static/pages/_app.js        869 B
  ├ chunks/commons.51ab52.js    9.98 kB
  ├ chunks/framework.21cc39.js  45.7 kB
  ├ runtime/main.85607a.js      5.47 kB
  └ runtime/webpack.dba809.js   1.22 kB
```

The "First Load" column seems strange to me, because the total size of all pages and the shared content displayed in the "Size" column sum to ~70kB only. I want to know how to check what are being included in the first load size and whether it is due to inefficient code that excess content is being loaded.

Comment: What about the size of next.js itself?

Answer (score 0):

instead of importing component in pages create container and import components in them
in pages : just import dynamically continers

```
import React  from 'react'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import { getTicketsCategory } from '@/actions/ticket-category'
import { wrapper } from '@/store/configureStore'


const ProfileBase=dynamic(() => import('container/Profile/Profile-Base'))
const AddTicket=dynamic(() => import('container/Profile/Ticket/New'))


function newTicket() {
    return (
        <ProfileBase >
            <AddTicket/>
        </ProfileBase>
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps=wrapper.getServerSideProps(
    async({store, req, res, ...etc}) => {
        await getTicketsCategory()
    }
)
export default wrapper.withRedux(newTicket)
```